# Eclipse IDE - Classnotfound exception even though path known. Why can Eclipse find the lib in one Project but not in the other?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, machine-learning

I am collaborating on a Project and we have a problem integrating some code I produced and that works in my local tesintg implementation of the jAudio library but once we include the library in the project (we all use eclipse) the project doesnt build throuwing the classnotfound exception - even though the IDE (Eclipse) knows the library (I can use autocomplete) and the methods are resolved it keeps insisting that it cannot resolve the classes to a type: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9tsa0xh1uq1kg8d/Screenshot%202014-01-18%2011.44.58.png "Example of Type not resolved"

What do you think might be the problem behind "I cant see you" problem ?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eExtractor.AudioFeatures.AreaPolynomialApproximationConstantQMFCC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at jAudioFeatureExtractor.ACE.XMLParsers.FeatureListHandler.endElement(FeatureListHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at jAudioFeatureExtractor.ACE.XMLParsers.XMLDocumentParser.parseXMLDocument(XMLDocumentParser.java:97)
    at jAudioFeatureExtractor.DataModel.<init>(DataModel.java:173)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.JAudioCommandLine.execute(JAudioCommandLine.java:47)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.AudioClassifierWithJAudio.privjanalyse(AudioClassifierWithJAudio.java:365)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.AudioClassifierWithJAudio.classifyAudioFile(AudioClassifierWithJAudio.java:223)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.AudioClassifierWithJAudio.main(AudioClassifierWithJAudio.java:57)
java.lang.Exception: The src\main\java\org\tuhh\cpmgg\weka\features.xml file must be of type feature_list. <ClassNotFoundException> Class 'eExtractor.AudioFeatures.AreaPolynomialApproximationConstantQMFCC' does not exist in the path.
    at jAudioFeatureExtractor.ACE.XMLParsers.XMLDocumentParser.parseXMLDocument(XMLDocumentParser.java:105)
    at jAudioFeatureExtractor.DataModel.<init>(DataModel.java:173)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.JAudioCommandLine.execute(JAudioCommandLine.java:47)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.AudioClassifierWithJAudio.privjanalyse(AudioClassifierWithJAudio.java:365)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.AudioClassifierWithJAudio.classifyAudioFile(AudioClassifierWithJAudio.java:223)
    at org.tuhh.cpmgg.weka.AudioClassifierWithJAudio.main(AudioClassifierWithJAudio.java:57)
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project and right click ----> Build path ----> configure buildpath and add that jar into your project.

just try this one.

Already you completed the Buildpath, restart the eclipse once. I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hi, Daniel did u check this one ?

Comment: I have done that at the very beginning of using jAudio - to no avail.

It is added as a zip (that is how jaudio is delivered) but it is also added through maven as a maven dependncy.

Comment: try once again for that zip file

Comment: I have done that already - it has not changed anything. 

Have you noticed that the **stacktrace** shows the name and package of the ** supposedly unresolvable class** not in full but **trimmed** - eExtractor.AudioFeatures.CLASS **instead** of FeatureExtractor.AudioFeatures.CLASS

Maybe this can be a useful hint ? I am at a loss still.